# How to play MJPEG(live stream) video in Media Player

Tags: android, android-webview, android-mediaplayer

I am working on an application in which I have to play video stream inside my app using Media 
Player in android. Its a live streaming video from CCTV, so I don't even know whether we can give Media Player a link to play video or not. Currently I am using a WebView to open the url from my app only but there is one more hurdle that this Video is only accessible from Mozilla FireFox, not from the other browser, so if the user dont have that browser it his/her device then it will not work. Thats why I am opening selection of browsers using the following code :-

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
```

But it will take the user to the selected browser outside the app,so I just want to know how can I resolve this to make it working.

No matter whether it can be done using Media Player or a webview but I want it within my app only, not outside my app. 
Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks